# Find furnace filter

Tags: furnace

I am a first time home owner, I tried to find and replace the filters because my Nest popped up reminding me. I have been searching everywhere around my furnace in the attic but can't find it.

It's a horizontal Gas Fired Heat furnace. Has the name Lincoln on it.

Comment: The furnace filter will typically be near where the return duct enters the air handler.  If you can provide a photograph of your furnace, including enough context to show the ducting in and out, we can properly direct your search.